# Which dev language to write an app without req. to install a framework?

Tags: programming-languages

Which dev language to write an app without req. to install a framework?

- Tool / App, not internet, not webpage
- windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/)—"a free Delphi".

  It's able to do static builds (I think this is even the default) so you should be able to create self-contained executables.
- Plain "old" Microsoft Visual Studio (might require distributing the VisualC++ runtime so might be not suitable).

If you do not need GUIs, then the possibilities are wider:

- Any powerful compiled language such as [Go](http://golang.org) or [D](http://dlang.org), [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html).
- Scripting languages working on Windows include (but are not limited to) [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk), Python and Perl.

  I'm not sure for the latter two, but Tcl [has tools](http://wiki.tcl.tk/starpack) which allow creation of self-contained executables which include both your program and all the packages it needs. And it has native Windows GUI toolkit, by the way, which also assigns it to the first category.
- Native scripting via Windows Scripting Host (WSH) can be done through JScript and VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) sounds like what you're looking for. It's a small, free scripting/automation language that seems fairly powerful. It also seems to be completely standalone:

> AutoIt is a very small and standalone application with no reliance on massive runtimes like .NET or VB. All you need to run AutoIt scripts are the main AutoIt executable (AutoIt3.exe) and the script. Scripts can also be encoded into standalone executables with the built-in script compiler Aut2Exe.

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is another scripting/automation language similar to AutoIt. Like AutoIt, it can

> Convert any script into an EXE file that can be run on computers that don't have AutoHotkey installed.

It also has the benefit of being able to run AutoIt v2 scripts.